# Filling in area above x-axis below a curve

Tags: matlab

I would like to fill in the area above the x-axis, below a curve. I have tried using: patch, fill, and area, but all of these result in the area being filled above the x-axis below the curve AND the area below the x-axis and above the curve. Consider this example:

```
t = 1:1024;
y = sin(t);
area(t, y)
axis([0,50,-2,2]);
```

I only want the top wiggles to be shaded, and not the bottom ones below x = 0.

I saw some code which defined two bounding curves, but this did not work either ie. I still get the same results as area, patch, and fill. The code was:

```
x = linspace(kokler(1),kokler(2)); % 100 points between intersections  
yy1 =x.^2; %lower function
yy2 = -(x.^2-16); % upper function
x = [x,x];        % repeat x values
yy = [yy1,yy2];   % vector of upper & lower boundaries
fill(x,yy,'b')    % fill area defined by x & yy in blue
```

Can any modifications be made to either these?

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```
figure,
t = 1:0.1:10*pi;
y = sin(t);
plot(t, y);

hold on;
y2 = y;
y2(y2 < 0) = 0;

area(t, y2);
```